# react native android build error Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderRelease'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

but I dont know how to fix it, can anyone help?

```
.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration4'.
   > Failed to transform jetified-openai-client-jvm.jar to match attributes {artifactType=ext-dex-dexBuilderRelease, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingExternalLibArtifactTransform: /Users/vedaxm1/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/928dde22c26711d4f6653c8bc3a3547a/transformed/jetified-openai-client-jvm.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform jetified-openai-core-jvm.jar to match attributes {artifactType=ext-dex-dexBuilderRelease, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingExternalLibArtifactTransform: /Users/vedaxm1/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9fe480a35ec85d3f1e16140437080db/transformed/jetified-openai-core-jvm.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

this error cause from `react-native-openai`, full-error log below: https://pastebin.com/XAn7y45r

## package.json

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.5",
    "react-native-openai": "^0.6.1",
```

Clean, rebuild, sync gradle again does not solved problem

Comment: My problem gone after check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71672710/1308590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer below:

```
pluginManagement {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools:r8:X.Y.Z")
            classpath('com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre')  // <-- THIS IS REQUIRED UNTIL R8 3.2.4-dev
        }
    }
}
```